# Dash modal popup toggle code isn't working

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am using a modal popup in my dash application. In the layout, I have 2 buttons defined. One
`Opens` the modal and other one `Closes` it. I referenced the example in documentation and using a slightly different code to listen to each button.

Upon close of the Modal, I'd like to call a function and run some other lines of code. However, I can't seem to listen to the button click of close button.

```
            # Modal buttons - layout code

            dbc.Button("Add", id="open-btn"),
 
            dbc.Button("Close", id="close-btn")


            # Callbacks
          
             # Modal toggle
             @app.callback(Output("modal-2", "is_open"),
             [
                  Input("open-btn", "n_clicks"),
                  Input("close-btn", "n_clicks")
             ],

             [
                  
                  State("Address", "value"),
                  State("City","value"),
                  State("Zip","value"),
                  State("State","value"),
                  State("modal-2", "is_open")
             ],
             )
            def add_prop(open_btn, close_btn, address, city, zip, state, is_open):

                 if open_btn:

                    return not is_open

                ## This code doesn't work 

                if close_btn:

                   print("Call function")
        
                   append_prop(tenant, industry, address, city, zip, state)

                   return is_open
```

I am trying to figure why the close pop up block of code isn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that `open_btn`, which is based on the `n_clicks` prop of that component, starts at a value of `0`. When the user clicks the button, it increments and the callback fires with `open_btn` having a value of `1`. That prop will retain the value for future calls to your callback. So, when the close button triggers the callback, `open_btn` still has a value of `1`, and the first `if` statement evaluates to `True`.

The way to solve this is with [`callback_context`](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks)

```py
def add_prop(open_btn, close_btn, address, city, zip, state, is_open):
    ctx = dash.callback_context

    if not ctx.triggered:
        button_id = 'No clicks yet'
    else:
        button_id = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]
```

Now you can check the value of `button_id` to see whether it was the open or close button that caused the callback to fire, and execute the proper part of your code.